# Force https for some pages and http for all others

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

In `.htaccess` (**Apache 2.4.6**) file i do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(login|checkout)\/?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

So, if my user get in `http://`**site/login** he is redirected to `https://`**site/login**. The same for `checkout` page.

But, for all others pages i do not want allow access to `https` protocol. In this cases i want force 301 redirect to `http` protocol.

For example: If my user access `https://`**site/products** i need it redirect him to `http://`**site/products**.

So, i added a new `RewriteCond` negating the regex, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/((?!login|checkout))\/?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

But it didn't work.

Any ideas for this problem? Tks.

### My .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/(login|checkout) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/(login|checkout) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# From /index.php/ to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The first rule, if my user get in on `/index.php/`login he is redirected to `/login`, removing the `/index.php/` from URI.

The last rule delegate all calls to index.php for `request dispatch` (front controller).

Answer (score 1):

Your negative lookahead doesn't seem to be correct.

And you can negate earlier URI matching condition in a simpler syntax also. So overall these 2 rules should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(login|checkout) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(login|checkout) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(login|checkout) [NC]
RewriteRule !^(login|checkout) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# From /index.php/ to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Delegate all requests to the index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Tks. But, with this rules, when i access /login or /checkout i'm being redirected to the index, always.

Comment: Yes, I had also fixed. Now, https to http, works fine! But, `http://`site/login back to index, also `https://`site/login.

Comment: Hmm that is definitely not because of these rules. Do you have other rules OR any other .htaccess on your system?

Comment: I have. I will test without it.

Comment: Also I believe `/login` or `/checkout` not real directories or files?

Comment: Yes, are page routes, not a dir or a file.

Comment: Tks. I've tested and when i access `http://`site/login or `https://`site/login keeps coming back to `http://`site/`index.php` and then `http://`site/ (without `index.php`).

Comment: I bet that is because of your last rule. Can you comment out `Delegate all requests to the index.php` rule and retest.

Comment: Without `Delegate all requests to the index.php` and with this changes ^`/index.php/`(login|checkout) and  !^`/index.php/`(login|checkout), worked fine! Thank you! But the URL got `/index.php/` in all requests. Any idea for solve this?

Comment: Can you update your .htaccess so that I can understand better and suggest accordingly.

Comment: Updated! I need to hide `/index.php/` from URL. The URI has to be passed to the index.php, but without the user see, like this rule does: http://pastebin.com/ffcHLsYz

Comment: Hmm I believe question has gone well beyond the actually stated problem of forcing http or https for certain URIs. On top of that I don't even know how `/login` is handled. Made a last attempt, see if that works out. If not then I suggest opening a new question since this question about https/http redirection.

Comment: I tried several other things, but it did not work. Thanks for your support!